# plotting real time data of mobile's accelerometer against time axis in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, accelerometer

I'm plotting real time data of accelerometer of mobile against time axis.`x-axis` will have time and `y-axis` will show values of accelerometer. I'm using `react-native-highcharts` for plotting data. But the output graph is blank. The code for live data plot is given at the URL https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts . In this code I'm just replacing `y` with `x-values` of accelerometer.

output is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### You are mutating state, which is a big no-no in React.

**State should be immutable at all times**, and only changed via a call to **`setState`**. If you are just directly mutating it like in your example, your component will not update.

I would advise you to learn more about [component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) in React (same in React Native) then you will realize how you can refactor your calls to `this.state.dataArr.push` and such.

**`render` should be a pure function** of `props` and `state`.

As we don't see the entire picture, only the render method (in the future please try to post a complete example) we can only make assumptions here.

I would imagine that in some of your other code you are recording the accelerometer and call `setState` to change `accelerometerData`. (If you are directly changing it via a regular assignment, change it to a `setState` call.) Then instead of mutating `dataArr` in the `render` method, change `dataArr` using the same `setState` call.

p.s. This is still not a perfect solution as it would still be using [derived state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html), but that is another - and slightly more advanced - topic to talk about.

Comment: I'm plotting graph between time and `z-axis` of accelerometer. `dataArr` is not a problem here . This is not involved in plotting. Plot is my main issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it is, always uses the latest Accelerometer data, i.e. you're always plotting one point (latest), and so the graph seems empty.

What you should do, make `accelerometedData` an Array in your state definition and then in `subscribe` push the data to it, instead of setting the latest point using `setState`, and plot from it to plot multiple points.

**EDIT**

To clarify:

Your state should be something like

```
state = {
  accelerometerData: []
};
```

Then your subscribe would be:

```
_subscribe = () => {
  this._subscription = Accelerometer.addListener(accelerometerData => {
    let data = this.state.accelerometerData;
    data.push(accelerometerData);
    this.setState({
      accelerometerData: data
    });
  });
};
```

And then inside `render()` you have `this.state.accelerometerData` which is arrray that you can use via `this.state.accelerometerData.map()` or similar

Comment: My subscribe function will look like this now `_subscribe = () => {
    this._subscription = Accelerometer.addListener(accelerometerData => {
      this.setState({ accelerometerData });
      this.accelerometedData.push(round(z));
      this.setState({ newAccelerometedData: accelerometedData});
    });
  };` It is giving an error like "undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.accelerometedData.push')" . I have  defined `accelerometedData`

Comment: Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {z, y, x}).